# Doubts in Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, information-theory

I meet one problem on the probability and statistic theory.

"Assume given the probability spaces $(X,S,\mu_i)$, $i=1,2$, and the probability space $(X,S,\lambda)$. And there exsit functions $f_i:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$, $i=1,2$, such that,
$$\mu_i(E)=\int_Ef_i(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x),\quad \forall E\in S.$$

$H_i$, $i=1,2$, is the hypothesis that $x$ is from the statistical population with probabilty measure $\mu_i$.

Then, we can derive the following relations from Bayes' Theorem, 
$$P(H_i|x)=\frac{P(H_i)f_i(x)}{P(H_1)f_1(x)+P(H_2)f_2(x)},\quad i=1,2.$$
"

I know the classic Bayes' Theorem, but I am confused about the last equality. How to deduce the last equality by Bayes' Theorem ?

Comment: perhaps this link will help http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Conditional.html

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, what you are saying is sometimes also expressed as $f(x|H_i)$ instead of $f_i(x)$. That is, the density given the specific model hypothesis. Then $P(H_i|x)=P(H_i, x)/f(x)=f(x|H_i)P(H_i)/(\sum_{i=1}^2 f(x|H_i)P(H_i))$ which is what you have, only different notation.